# check if a string contains non-english words in java

Tags: java, tokenize, non-english

I would like to know if there is a way to check if a given string may contain English word and returns the non-English substrings.
What I've tried so far is to load an English dictionary to a file and check the existence of an English word in my strings by comparing my input with the words in the dictionary file, however this approach is so complicated, I would like to know if there's a better way to do it especially in terms of performance.
Example :

```
"here are english words this hdksn is not" => true, hdksn is not in english
```

**true** means here that is contains at least one english word.

Ps : my strings are actually mysql rows and i'm working with Java

Comment: I don't see how you could find a simpler approach than that. Regarding the performance, it should be fast as hell, unless you're doing something wrong. But you didn't post any code, so...

Comment: You could make some small improvements to performance if you know a little more about the words you're reviewing. If it's natural language - like transcripts from a conversation - you can assume that some words will appear much more frequently than others. In this case, it might be worthwhile to load the dictionary not as a file, but as a splay tree. If you cannot assume anything on the words you're getting - just use the dictionary approach you have.

Comment: @Assafs I don't seem to have something frequent, thank you